# Javascript Anti-Pattern - Returning a new Promise from async function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

**Is returning an unresolved manually created Promise from an async function considered an anti-pattern?**

As async functions return promises by default, it is a little strange to build a `new Promise` and return it from the same `async` function.

I have two different methods, in the first one, I have doubts as to whether or not I am doing the `new Promise` constructor anti-pattern. In the other one, I am definitely sure that it is an anti-pattern.

**First function:**

```
export default async (uri) => {
  const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onload = function () {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };

    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
      reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
    };

    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });

  return blob;
};
```

**Second function:**

```
export async function uploadImageToStorage(
  imageUri,
  storageFolder = "images",
  stateObserver = undefined
) {
  const blob = await uriToBlob(imageUri);

  const imageId = blob._data.blobId;

  const storageRef = storage.ref(storageFolder).child(imageId);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    storageRef.put(blob).on(
      "state_changed",
      stateObserver,
      function error(err) {
        blob.close();
        reject(err);
      },
      function complete() {
        blob.close();
        resolve(imageId);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Is it considered to be an anti-pattern the first method implementation?

In the second function, as `storageRef.put(blob).on()` doesn't return a Promise, my api is callback-based, I need to wrap it inside a Promise, resolving in a `complete()` callback. If I refactor it to:

```
export async function uploadImageToStorage(
  imageUri,
  storageFolder = "images",
  stateObserver = undefined
) {
  const blob = await uriToBlob(imageUri);

  const imageId = blob._data.blobId;

  const storageRef = storage.ref(storageFolder).child(imageId);

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    storageRef.put(blob).on(
      "state_changed",
      stateObserver,
      function error(err) {
        blob.close();
        reject(err);
      },
      function complete() {
        blob.close();
        resolve(imageId);
      }
    );
  });
  
  return imageId;
}
```

The new implementation would not be considered as an anti-pattern right?

Comment: Could you clarify what anti-pattern you are referring to? Maybe a link?

Comment: @Thomas I thought that the anti-pattern was unnecessarily wrapping Promise Objects inside Promise Objects. In the code I provided, I returned a Promise Object from a function tagged as an `async` function - which by definition forces the function to return a Promise Object.

Comment: so, `new Promise(new Promise()) = anti-pattern` ?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with this in either case. You have to return a `Promise`, but the API you are using is callback-based, so you *have* to wrap it in a manually created `Promise` at some point.

However, there's no point `await`ing that `Promise` within your `async` function if all you're going to do is return the value that it resolved to. In that case you can just return the unresolved `Promise` directly.

After doing that, if you are no longer using `await` in the function, you could also remove the `async` keyword. But I would leave it in as a signal to the casual reader that the return value will be a `Promise`.